# cakephp AJAX while using amason ecs search

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, cakephp

I am using ajax to fetch results from amazon ecs.

The code is given below. It is not fetching results from amazon. If I used same in normal page function,it is working. In AJAX ,it is not fetching results from amazon. Please help me to solve this.

```
if($this->data && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){             
            $this->loadModel('Amazon');

            $result = array();

        $response = $this->Amazon->items('All', array('Keywords' => 'Apple','info' => 'ItemAttributes,Images,SalesRank,EditorialReview','sortby'=>'price','relevant','ItemPage' => '1'));
        $result['totalpage'] = $response['StdClass']['Items']['TotalPages'];

        foreach($response['StdClass']['Items']['Item'] as $key => $val){
                $result['data'][] = $val;           
        }           


        $this->set('json_data',$result); 
        $this->render('/elements/json');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're including the `RequestHandler` component in your Controller's `components` property:

```
/**
 * use the RequestHandler component
 */
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

And you'll also want to set your `layout` to false.

```
if ($this->data && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {

  $this->layout = false;

  // ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks Moz,It is not the issue of RequestHandler .Same ajax function is working for static data.It may be  due to time requires to fetch records from amazon..